DuckDB: parquet predicate pushdown with more than one clause?
I have a parquet file of tickdata ordered (and row-chunked) by instrument-symbol. The parquet file metadata contains min/max metadata. I've found that if my query asks for a single symbol in the where clause then duckdb performs predicate pushdown on the parquet file, but with more than one symbol it doesn't.
(1) one symbol in filter => predicate pushdown

explain analyse SELECT * from "/data/phil/cme_312.parquet" AS t
‣ WHERE t.symbol = 'SR3Z3';


┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│       PARQUET_SCAN        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           symbol          │
│         event_type        │
│            side           │
│         symbol_idx        │
│           epoch           │
│           price           │
│          quantity         │
│        msg_seq_num        │
│       transact_time       │
│          n_orders         │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│ Filters: symbol=SR3Z3 AND │
│     symbol IS NOT NULL    │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│        EC: 2820388        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           250614          │
│          (0.36s)          │
└───────────────────────────┘


(2) two symbols in filter => unfiltered scan

explain analyse SELECT * from "/data/phil/cme_312.parquet" AS t
‣ WHERE t.symbol = 'SR3Z3' or t.symbol = 'SR3H4';


┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│       PARQUET_SCAN        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           symbol          │
│         event_type        │
│            side           │
│         symbol_idx        │
│           epoch           │
│           price           │
│          quantity         │
│        msg_seq_num        │
│       transact_time       │
│          n_orders         │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│        EC: 14101941       │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│          14101941         │
│          (6.37s)          │
└───────────────────────────┘


Is this a limitation of duckdb parquet support?
(this is duckdb v0.10.2)
